# If Remote Desktop is disabled on a PC, can I still alternatives for RMC?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, lan

Basically the title says it all. 
If built in remote desktop is disabled on a machine, can I still user third party software like teamviewer to remotely access said machine via my LAN?

Comment: That's going to depend on the particular remote package you're trying to use - some of them require that the standard remote desktop capability be enabled, because they "piggyback" on it and possibly add capabilities. Check the documentation for the package(s) you are interested in using.

Comment: can you name me one which isnt piggybacking? :D

Comment: Actually, I believe that Dameware doesn't require Remote Desktop Services to be enabled... But I'm not familiar with all the options out there, so you'll need to do your own homework on that. Perhaps asking an appropriate question over in [softwarerecs.se] will give you some ideas to follow up on.